# How to return the whole array instead of a single string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to return all words which have more than four letters in the below exercise.

```
def timed_reading(max_length, text)
  var_b = text.split(" ")

  var_b.map do |i|
    if i.length >= max_length
      return i
    end
  end
end

print timed_reading(4,"The Fox asked the stork, 'How is the soup?'")
# >> asked
```

I seem to get only one word.

Comment: Unrelated, but meaningful variable names go a long way, e.g., `words` and `word` have much more meaning than `var_b` and `i`. In any case, you're returning from the function as soon as you hit the first word longer than `max_length`. And you don't want `map`, you want to gather only those elements that meet the requirement: `map` will create a value for every object in the array it's called on.

Comment: Another thing is to use `split(/\s+/)` to split on *one or more spaces* as well.

Comment: ...and I think `min_length` would be a better choice for the variable name than `max_length`, since you want to select words whose length is at least a a given minimum value.

Comment: @tadman, or just `split` with no argument.

Comment: You state, "...words which have more than 4 letters.". To be consistent with your code that should be  "...words which have 4 or more letters.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter a list and select only certain kinds of entries, use the [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) method:

```
var_b.select do |i|
  i.length >= max_length
end
```

Where that's all you need.

The `return i` in the middle is confusing things, as that breaks out of the loop and returns a single value *from the method itself*. Remember that in Ruby, unlike others such as JavaScript, `return` is often implied and doesn't need to be spelled out explicitly.

Blocks don't normally have `return` in them for this reason unless they need to interrupt the flow and break out of the method itself.

Comment: Many thanks. All makes sense now (and of course works)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to first extract all words from the string and then select those having at least four letters. Instead you can just extract the desired words using [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression.

```
str = "The Fox asked the stork, 'How is the soup?'? Très bon?"

str.scan /\p{Alpha}{4,}/
  #=> ["asked", "stork", "soup", "Très"]
```

The regular expression reads, "Match strings containing 4 or more letters". I've used `\p{Alpha}` (same as `\p{L}` and `[[:alpha:]]`) to match unicode letters. (These are documented in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html). Search for these expressions there.) You could replace `\p{Alpha}` with `[a-zA-Z]`, but in that case "Très" would not be matched.

If you wish to also match digits, use `\p{Alnum}` or `[[:alnum:]]` instead. While `\w` also matches letters (English only) and digits, it also matches underscores, which you probably don't want in this situation.

Punctuation can be a problem when words are extracted from the string by splitting on whitespace.

```
arr = "That   is a cow.".split
  #=> ["That", "is", "a", "cow."]
arr.select { |word| word.size >= 4 }
  #=> ["That", "cow."]
```

but `"cow"` has only three letters. If you instead used `String#scan` to extract words from the string you obtain the desired result.

```
arr = "That   is a cow?".scan /\p{Alpha}+/
  #=> ["That", "is", "a", "cow"]
arr.select { |word| word.size >= 4 }
  #=> ["That"]
```

However, if you use `scan` you may as well use a regular expression to retrieve only words having at least 4 characters, and skip the extra step.